# Adding an image to a navbar using html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image fit to the left side of a navbar using only pure html and css. So far, I haven't made the actual  **nav li** links but here's what I have:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_class {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="container nav_class">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://odysseeservice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Microsoft-Dynamics-NAV-Logo.png" alt="">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"></li>
        <li class="nav-link"></li>
        <li class="nav-link"></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I wouldn't like it to be more than 80px in height. Just the image on the left and 3 nav one-word nav links on the right.
I understand how to create the nav links and get all of the container children to be side by side but I cant figure out how to get the image to be smaller and on a fixed position in the navbar.

Guess what I'm basically asking is how to get the image fit the container and how to even make a proper container for it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the container of the img is `80px`, then setting the img to have `height: 100%` will give it 80px of height and it will automatically scaling it.
Then you can use flexbox to help you with the positioning. Something like this:

```css
    #nav-bar{
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #nav-bar img{
        height: 100%;
    }
    .nav-links{
        display: flex;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
        <img id="header-img" src="https://odysseeservice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Microsoft-Dynamics-NAV-Logo.png" alt="">            
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>A</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: good start, however you should fix the overflow issue and should try it without restructuring the HTML (espacially without mentioning it) which is easily possible.

Comment: After trying out the other options I've decided that this is the best solution. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit` property for this. Just give a full height and width to your image and force the image to contain its parent.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

**EDIT:** You can learn more about this property on this page.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
            max-width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* overflow: ; */
            padding: 0 40px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between ;
        }
        /* that will make image fit */
        img {
            width: 25%;
        }
        /* make the navbar and take every thing inside */
        .nav_class {
            height: 80px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #nav-bar ul{
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
            display:flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to your CSS code:

`.container { display: grid; grid-template-columns: min-content auto; }`

Those 2 lines change the header container to a grid where the logo will use up as much space as needed without changing the size format. The navbar will take up all remaining space.

Then I delted your CSS code for the image and replaced it with the `header-img` id to not influence other images:

`#header-img { max-height: 80px; }`

This will ensure that the logo will not use up more then 80px height and will take as much width as needed without changign the size ratio.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}

#header-img {
  max-height:80px;
}

.nav_class {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="container nav_class">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://odysseeservice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Microsoft-Dynamics-NAV-Logo.png" alt="">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"></li>
        <li class="nav-link"></li>
        <li class="nav-link"></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```